# Как научить EF Core 2 строить запросы UNION

Tags: entity-framework-core

EF Core 2 не умеет транслировать методы Queryable.Concat и Queryable.Union

Ef Core 3.1 умеет

Не могу найти в исходниках 3.1 как он это делает. Ткните носом, пожалуйста.

Comment: с чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @Yaroslav что с чего взял?

Comment: что Concat  и Union не работают!

Comment: @Yaroslav ну это же просто. Попробуйте в EFcore2 выполнить такой запрос `var unionAll = await dbContext.MyEntities.Concat(dbContext.MyEntities).ToListAsync();`

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6812

Comment: https://github.com/tuespetre/Impatient

Comment: @Yaroslav, у меня не sqlserver.